# Python2 -> Python3 Socket is non-blocking in python2, but blocks longer in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

Attempting to use socket.recv and socket.sendto(), to a host thats not available on the lan with a UDP socket.

System is the same architecture for both python versions, just different pythons.

Windows 10 Pro x64
Python 2.7 to Python 3.8

In both python2 and python3 versions, the socket that is receiving is being set with socket.setblocking(0), but for some reason the python3 equivalent is taking decidedly longer to receive data. It's almost as if it's still set to blocking, or is awaiting responses before timing out.

The data being sent and received is flowing at about 100htz a second, if that helps.

```py
s_from_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # UDP
s_from_server.setblocking(0)
```

Setup, then

```py
 s_from_dspace.bind((ANY_IP, RX_SERVER_PORT))
```

The socket is binded.

```py
data_server = s_from_server.recv(364)
```

Rest of the code is then done via the data received.

---

Here's an example of sending data

```py
s_to_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # UDP
bytes_to_server = struct.pack('H', gpsWeek)
bytes_to_server += struct.pack('dd', gpsSOW, utcTime)
s_to_server.sendto(bytes_to_server, (SERVER_UDP_IP, TX_SERVER_PORT))
```

---

I'm just not sure what changed between Python 2 and Python 3 to cause this sort of lag. Python2 felt almost instantaneous in all aspects, but the python3 code feels like its hanging on every response. Any help is appreciated! <3

Answer (score 0):

With UDP I think you should use `socket.recvfrom` and specify the number of bytes you expect to receive, e.g. `socket.recvfrom(4096)`. 4096 is an arbitrary number here, you should add your own based on the server protocol.